# Report command only detects the command itself, but not the user mentioned

Tags: discord.js

Kind of new in the sphere of scripting bots, so looked up some tutorials and was trying to make a report command, when I write !report it says 'User not found', but when I write the full command ( !report @someone test) it doesn't send anything.

I have tried copying the code from GitHub but nothing helped, changed a lot of things around but still, no result.

```
    //!report @ned this is the reason

    let rUser = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[1]));
    if(!rUser) return message.channel.send("Couldn't find user.");
    let rreason = args.join(" ").slice(22);


    let reportEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setDescription("Reports")
    .setColor("#15f153")
    .addField("Reported User", `${rUser} with ID: ${rUser.id}`)
    .addField("Reported By", `${message.author} with ID: ${message.author.id}`)
    .addField("Reported in", message.channel)
    .addField("Reported at", message.createdAt)
    .addField("Report reason", rreason);

    let reportschannel = message.guild.channels.get("603857301392195585")
    if(!reportschannel) return message.channel.send("Couldn't find reports channel.");


    message.delete().catch(O_o=>{});
    reportschannel.send(reportEmbed);

    return;
  }
```

There was no errors, nothing in the command prompt.

Comment: I didn't have any problem with your code. I changed it a bit for the sake of my test but even with the original one, it was sending embed message. https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDIZk.png I advice that you try to log what is happening in your code to discover what error you could have (which I suppose is linked to your discord server)

Comment: Did log and nothing in there, heres the image of what happens: http://imgur.com/a/a4VWvYw

Comment: Hum. Simple suggestion to check. Can you replace `reportschannel.send...` by `message.channel. send... ` at the end?

Comment: Still doesn't send it

Comment: Well I tought that you had a wrong channel ID but apparently no. You're code is working so it must be a: version problem, a problem with discord or something else linked to yiu environment. Try to break your code in part. Log each variable to check if it has a defined value. Check if each action is made. For example replace `reportsEmbed` by `'test' `. and do small action like this to check what works what doesn't work

Answer (score -3):

**1.** You forgot to set a title/author in your embed. I don't know if its needed but you should add something like this. Then you can remove `.setDescription()`.

```
// [...]
let reportEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
 .setAuthor("Reports")
 .setColor("#15f153")
// [...]
```

**2.** You can leave out the part after `message.delete()`, there is no `.catch()` needed.

**3.** Remove `return;` at the end. It's not needed either.

---

Also check if you are running this.
E.g. use debug messages. After almost every line a `console.log("1")`, `console.log("2")` etc. to check, where the code stops.

Example:

```
//!report @ned this is the reason

let rUser = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[1]));    
if(!rUser) return message.channel.send("Couldn't find user.");
console.log("1") // User exists
let rreason = args.join(" ").slice(22);
console.log("2") // No reason creating problems


let reportEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
 .setAuthor("Reports")
 .setColor("#15f153")
 .addField("Reported User", `${rUser} with ID: ${rUser.id}`)
 .addField("Reported By", `${message.author} with ID: ${message.author.id}`)
 .addField("Reported in", message.channel)
 .addField("Reported at", message.createdAt)
 .addField("Report reason", rreason);

 let reportschannel = message.guild.channels.get("603857301392195585");
 if(!reportschannel) return message.channel.send("Couldn't find reports channel.");
 console.log("3") // Channel exists


 message.delete();
 console.log("4") // Message deleted
 reportschannel.send(reportEmbed);
 console.log("5") // Report message sent
```

Comment: While I agree that the `.catch` as it's written in his code is useless, I disagree with what you say about removing it. It's important to catch promise in case it fails. Also not saying to not return a value at the end while the rest of the function return string isn't good. If a value is supposed to be used, `undefined` could cause error. Lastly, you're not answering the question, only giving advice. You're not addressing the issue. Your answer should be a comment

Comment: I agree with what Jack said. You should be giving SUGGESTIONS in comments. Ive noticed you went around answering every single Discord.js question you could. Don't answer unless what you are saying is going to work, and or you have tested it. Answers shouldn't have things like " I don't know if this is needed but you should add it" should more be like "This is what i tried and it worked for me. Try it out" with that being said, its not good practice to just grab chunks of code off Github, slap it into your code and hope it works with minimal changes. I suggest doing free code camp to learn .js

Comment: correcting a mistake btw: the function return Promise, not string

Comment: @JackRed The attached `catch()` method as written will suppress any error arising from a rejected promise. Without it, an UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning (along with the error) would be seen. In terms of its purpose, it's useless in this scenario, but removing it entirely would produce a much different result. @Xge "*...there is no `.catch()` needed.*" It's not *required*, but to catch a rejected promise (good/normal practice), it certainly is.

Comment: @slothiful it's why I said 'as it's written in the code it's useless'. I can't edit to make more clear tho, hopefully your comment will be enough